# Выбор цвета фона пользователем

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы пользователь мог сам выбирать цвет фона сайта, т. е. фона `body` пользуясь чем-то на подобие *Сolor Picker*. Подскажите, где можно найти решение? Потом я бы хотел сделать тоже самое, только градиент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то в роде этого?

```js
var colorPicker = document.getElementById("bgcolor");

function changebodycolor(){
   var colorVal = colorPicker.value;
   document.body.style.background = colorVal;
}

colorPicker.addEventListener("change",
changebodycolor,false);
```

```css
body {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.colorPicker {width: 100px; height: 52px; background-color: blue; margin: 10px;
text-align: center}
.colorPicker input {width: 80%; height: 80%; transform: translateY(8%);}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
Выберите цвет для тела документа:
   <div class="colorPicker">
     <input type="color" id="bgcolor"/>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Но внимание! Не все даже не очень старые браузеры поддерживают `input[type=color]`. Подробнее: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color

Насчет градиента: если линейный градиент, то это не очень сложно (смотря сколько цветов будет в нём – если до 4-х цветов, то особо сложного ничего нет), но если радильный, то это уже запарка серьёзная.

Пример градиента с 4-мя цветами (я уверен это не лучший вариант, жду поправок и критики):

```js
var colorPicker = document.getElementById("bgcolor");
var colorVal;
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".colors");
var done = document.getElementById("doIt");

function changebodycolor(){
 colorVal = colorPicker.value;
 document.getElementById("colorContainer").value = colorVal;}

colorPicker.addEventListener("change",
changebodycolor,false);

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
   buttons[i].onclick = function(){
      if(colorContainer.value.trim().length < 1)
   {return false;}
   
   else {
        this.innerHTML = colorVal;
     }
   };
}

doIt.onclick = function(){
   var gradient = "linear-gradient(to top,"
   + buttons[0].innerHTML + ","
   + buttons[1].innerHTML  + ","
   + buttons[2].innerHTML  + ","
   + buttons[3].innerHTML  + ")";
   document.body.style.background = gradient;
 };
```

```css
body {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.colorPicker {width: 100px; height: 52px; background-color: blue; margin: 10px;
text-align: center}
.colorPicker input {width: 80%; height: 80%; transform: translateY(8%);}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
Выберите цвет для тела документа:<br/>
Тип: градиент
   <div class="colorPicker">
     <input type="color" id="bgcolor"/><br/>
     <input type="hidden" id="colorContainer" value=""/>
   </div>
     <button class="colors">Цвет 1</button>
     <button class="colors">Цвет 2</button>
     <button class="colors">Цвет 3</button>
     <button class="colors">Цвет 4</button>
     <button id="doIt">Применить</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Да, отлично, именно то, что надо, благодарю Вас!)

Comment: один вопрос - как зафиксировать этот фон? Т.е. чтобы он не создавался вновь при прокручивании... я добавил в css строчку: position: fixed;, но не помогло

Comment: @user250973 `background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;` и все это для `body` пропиши. И еще: почитай [эту статью на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/282079/), будет полезной.

Comment: полезная статья, да.. изменил по ней.. но правда всё равно прокручивается.. т.е. у меня и до этого если фон картинка, то она фиксирована, и сейчас после изменений из хабра картинка фиксирована, а вот градиент прокручивается

Answer (score 0):

У `JQuery` есть уже готовые решения. Например. `jQuery Color Picker`.

Скачать здесь: [download jQuery Color Picker](https://jqueryui.com/download/)

Как встраивать: [manual jQuery Color Picker](https://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-color-picker/)

Другие варианты:
[Other](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-color-pickers-plugin/)

Comment: Как будто в html5 нет